# Two endpoints for same controller (route aliases) in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I want to change an entity name from **Person** to **Individual**. I want to keep the old `/person` endpoint (for temporary backward compatibility) and add a new `/individual` endpoint.

What would be the easiest way to do it in Node.js using Nest?

I can copy the code but I'm hoping for a better solution that won't require duplication

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `@Controller()` decorator accepts an array of prefix, thus you can use like this:

```js
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller(['person', 'individual'])
export class IndividualController {
  @Get()
  findAll(): { /* ... */ }
}
```

to me this is the easiest way.

[source](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/149483a852a70f0b095997450889442ed93bc3b8/packages/common/decorators/core/controller.decorator.ts#L77)

Comment: This is exactly what I need but seems that maybe I'm using an older version of Nest. What version are you using?

Comment: this feature was added on [Nestjs v6](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/v7.6.0/packages/common/decorators/core/controller.decorator.ts)

Answer (score 8):

In NestJS, We can have multiple routes for the whole controller or for a single route. This is supported for all HTTP methods (POST, GET, PATCH etc., )

```
@Controller(['route-1', 'route-2'])
export class IndividualController {

  @Get(['/sub-route-1','/sub-route-2'])
  public async getSomething(...){...}
```

All HTTP methods support either a single string route or an array of string routes. We could use this technique to deprecate a bad route and start introducing a better route without breaking the consumers immediately.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean `expressjs` instead of `jestjs` (which is a testing framework), my approach would be the following:

simply exclude your controller code into a function and pass it to your routes.

```js
// your controller code
const doSomethingWithPersonEntity = (req, res, next) => {
   res.status(200).json(persons);
}

router.get("/person", doSomethingWithPersonEntity);
router.get("/individual", doSomethingWithPersonEntity);
```